# Buying in the Mac App Store for the enterprise

Tags: macos, mac, applications, mac-appstore, license

We're looking to buy an app in the Mac App Store ([iBarcoder](https://itunes.apple.com/ca/app/ibarcoder/id439864161?mt=12)) for our graphic designers using Macs, and after read [this article](http://www.macworld.com/article/1156962/mac_app_store_faq.html) on Macworld.com, we're not too sure how to go about it.

> **Does that mean I could buy one copy of an app and install it on every Mac in my business?**
>
> No, the license you agree to when you enter the Mac App Store says
>   that app downloads are for Macs that you personally own, and that's a
>   license for personal use. Apps that are intended for professional use
>   are licensed for you or for a single computer used by several people.
>   While there's no technical impediment to you installing them on
>   multiple Macs at work, you'll be violating the license agreement. It's
>   the same scenario as if you buy a single-user copy of iWork and
>   install it on ten Macs at work—you can do it, but you're violating the
>   license agreement, making the act ethically questionable.

We know about the volume licensing that Apple offers, but it seems as though it's only for education and not for the enterprise. Surely creating a new Apple ID for every Mac isn't the best way to do this, right?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apple also has a [Volume Purchase Program for Business](http://www.apple.com/business/vpp/), which it says is applicable "whether you have ten employees or ten thousand". I didn't see anything saying it couldn't actually be used for even fewer than 10 employees/users, too. There doesn't appear to be a minimum quantity for VPP license purchases (that I could find, anyway).

If you choose to enroll, you'll need to set up a new Apple ID using an email that isn't already tied to an existing Apple ID.

You can find more information in the [VPP Guide (PDF)](http://images.apple.com/business/docs/VPP_Business_Guide.pdf).

Comment: VPP Guide link is dead.

Comment: Found working link, fixed it.